# Resource not found - Triggering BitBucket Pipeline using curl

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, bitbucket-api

I created a new project and added a repository to it in my workspace. Further, I added a `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` to build a pipeline. I am able to trigger the pipeline manually however while trying to execute it using BitBucket API using curl, I get the below error every time:

Can anyone suggest what I am missing here?

**NOTE:** The same curl command (below) is able to run other pipelines in different repositories in the same workspace, so do I need to enable something in my current repository to access pipeline using BitBucket APIs. TIA

**Error:**

```
{"type": "error", "error": {"message": "Resource not found"}}%
```

**cURL command:**

```
curl -X POST -is -u username:password \
        -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
        https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/workspace-name/repo-name/pipelines/ \
        -d '
        {
            "target": {
            "type": "pipeline_ref_target",
            "ref_type": "branch",
            "ref_name": "master",
            "selector": {
            "type": "custom",
            "pattern": "create-tenant"
        }
       }}'
```

Answer (score 2):

So the tokens I was using in the curl weren't added to `Repository Settings` -> `User and group access`. Got them added and was able to execute it successfully.